# Materialio Appbar does not hide when scrolling down

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-appbarlayout, google-material-icons

I've followed the [material documentation for top app bars](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar) and implemented a part of it in my app to be able to hide it, when scrolling down my list.

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/ddd"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context=".pkgTestforend.DriverListFragment">

    <com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgTestforend.CustomLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cusLL"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listAllDrivers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

    </com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgTestforend.CustomLinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true" >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="PageTitle"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the corresponding fragment:

```
public class DriverListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public DriverListFragment() {
    }

    public static DriverListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        return  new DriverListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driver_list, container, false);
        setUpToolbar(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setUpToolbar(View view) {
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
    }

    ListView listViewDriver;
    DriverListAdapter adapter;
    RoomWithRxJavaViewModel viewModel;
    
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listViewDriver = view.findViewById(R.id.listAllDrivers);
        viewModel = new RoomWithRxJavaViewModel(getActivity().getApplication());
    
           Disposable d = viewModel.getDrivers()
            .subscribe(allusers ->
                {
                    adapter = new DriverListAdapter(getContext(), (ArrayList<Driver>) allusers);
                    listViewDriver.setAdapter(adapter);

                }, e -> {
                    //show err mes
                }

            );
    }

}
```

The setup is pretty simple build.
I just have a custom linearlayout which I am planning to modify later. And yes, the relative layout for the listview is on purpose so I can easily modify my future button positions.

The result looks like this:

[image: example]

So the issue is that, altough the app bar at the top is visible, it wont hide when I scroll down my list (see picture above), eventough I am using `app:liftOnScroll="true"` and `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`.

What am I missing exactly? Is it cause I use my custom linearlayout?
Putting the appbar before the custom linearlayout didn't change the output unfourntatly.